# Calling Click event of button of form on panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I have one tabstrip control having two tabs.
On one tab i have Panel control where i have showed another form and this other form have one button "Submit".
On other tab i have some controls and one button "OK".
Now on clicking "OK" button i have to call the click event of "Submit" button of the form on panel on other tab.
All this is in windows application in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the form into the panel, you'll need to call AddHandler to add the submit button's click event handler as an event handler for the OK button.  For instance:

```
AddHandler btnOk.Click, AddressOf childForm.btnSubmit_Click
```